# Ubuntu 22.04 shows default icons on Dock when using shortcut

Tags: 22.04, icons

[image: dock icon is broken]

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, whenever I open Terminator using the shortcut (alt+Ctrl+T) it comes up as a broken(default?) icon in the dock.

If I open the same via clicking the icon it comes correctly.

Any idea what could be the issue? or where I should check to figure it out?

Comment: @guiverc issue is that one instance of terminator shows up with the icon of terminator, another instance runs as a separate icon, that even does not adopt the installed terminator icon. Just a few minutes ago I could reproduce two icons (both terminator, though) myself, but I cannot anymore, Normal situation is that it runs under a single icon - WM_CLASS of both instances was the same.

Comment: @guiverc - I am running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @vanadium is correct, I have the icon for terminator already, its the 5th icon in the screenshot. If I open it via clicking the icon it loads correctly. But if I open terminator via the shortcut - it comes up as the icon missing case shown in the diagram.

Comment: Problem is, I cannot reproduce the issue on a standard Ubuntu 22.04 running on Wayland (I run Xorg myself with a Gnome session). Temporarily create a new account and see if the issue also happens there - will show whether this is an issue with the account configuration or not. If yes, you could try if deleting all hidden configuration folders of terminator solves the issue (after which you will need to configure terminator again).

Comment: @vanadium - thank you. I tried a different user and that too has the same issue. I assume the issue is because I did an inplace upgrade. I will try switching to XOrg.

Comment: yup - swtching back to Xorg - I dont have that issue anymore. I guess I will stay of Wayland for the timebeing.